# Reg-Free COM in an ASP.Net application

Tags: asp.net, com

I am wondering if it is possible to use Reg-Free COM in an ASP.Net application?

Comment: On the server or on the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this it is: http://www.mazecomputer.com/sxs/help/iis6aspnet2.htm

I haven't tried, it I've just been researching the same idea...

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to take a look at that.